# Javascript init() function isn't being called automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

I'm using this syntax for my class creation (jQuery):

```
$.myClass = function() {}
$.myClass.prototype = {
    init: function() {
        console.log('initializing');
    },
    someFunc: function() = {
        console.log('some function is being called');
    }
}
```

When I call

```
var myClassObj = new $.myClass();
```

My `init()` function isn't being called, I have to call it manually. How do I edit my class's default initialization function instead of creating a separate one?

Comment: `$.myClass = function() {this.init();}`

Comment: Oh my god thank you. I'm dumb.

Comment: JSHINT or JSLINT is your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed this -

```
$.myClass = function() 
    {
      this.init();
    }
```

Comment: Thats exactly it. Durr. Thanks a bunch!